# Matching a Comma Separated List

Tags: python, regex

I have a sample string like so:

```
[{HST, AKST, PST, MST, CST, EST, AST, WAT, CET, GMT, EET, CCT, AWST, JST, EAST, NZT} {0:10}]
```

I'm interested in the first set of items in brackets:

```
{HST, AKST, PST, MST, CST, EST, AST, WAT, CET, GMT, EET, CCT, AWST, JST, EAST, NZT}
```

I would like parse the set and put it into a list. I'm working with python.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  you want a regex that will match all elements of this list individually?  Or do you want to split the list into an array or something for easier processing?

Comment: The latter. Splitting doesn't work because it's part of a larger string.

Comment: Are you wanting to determine if the value of a given variable is found in the comma-separated list? What is your comma-separated list stored in? You mentioned it was part of a larger string. Please give us much more info.

Comment: If it's part of a larger string, you can use `substring()` to get just the comma-separated list out. Or you can split it about the '{' and '}' characters first.

Comment: I've made more edits. Is that enough information? Sorry for not being clear before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for match in re.finditer("(?i)[a-z]+", subject):
    # match start: match.start()
    # match end (exclusive): match.end()
    # matched text: match.group()
```

This will help you iterate through the "elements" of your list.

EDIT : You **now** write it's part of a larger string. That changes the original question.

```
for match in re.finditer(r"(?i)(?:(\b[a-z]+\b)[,}])", subject):
    # match start: match.start()
    # match end (exclusive): match.end()
    # matched text: match.group(1)
```

This will find your list and extract the words inside it.

Answer (score 0):

A regex just creates tokens, you'll need to do stuff with them afterwards. Luckily, the standard regex lib for python includes a function to give you all of the values it finds.

```
import re
input = '{HST, AKST, PST, MST, CST, EST, AST, WAT, CET, GMT, EET, CCT, AWST, JST, EAST, NZT}'
data = re.findall(r'\w+', input)
```

Also, this will find all "words". Depending on what's valid input, you may need a more powerful regex. Additional details would be helpful in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

to split the string, you can use `string.split(s,',')`. this will return a list of string based on s that are split about the character ','.

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

To get just this list out of a larger string, split about the '{' and '}' characters first.